# Loop doesn't work

Tags: categories, loop, sidebar

I'm making a box in my sidebar that shows a list of articles from a single category:

```
 <?php
// The Query
query_posts('cat=31&posts_per_page=5');
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <?php the_title(); ?></a> <span>Di <?php the_author(); ?>, <?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></span></li>

<?php
endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

But, this piece of code doesn't work. The `<ul>` tag is empty when the page is rendered.

Comment: Never use `query_posts()`, but use [`WP_Query()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/22728) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if your post_type is not post you will need to amend the code)

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'cat'  => '31',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>    

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <?php the_title(); ?></a> <span>Di <?php the_author(); ?>, <?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></span></li>

<?php

endwhile;
endif;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```